# DynamicDataRoute with Vs2013 .Net 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, visual-studio-2013, dynamic-data

I have an old WebForms project in which I successfully add Dynamic feature a few years ago. I also add routing with DynamicDataRoute. All worked fine.

Now, with VS2013 4.5, I create a new web project with both WebForms, MVC and ApiWeb.
I use the same code for rooting dynamic data. 
Two things doesn't works :

1/ Urls like "xxx/Pages/Page.aspx" are displayed in Url bar as "xxx/Pages/Page" but works fine.

2/ Routes like "WebSite/XXX/id" doesn't work (404).

What did I make wrong?  Thanks.

Here is my rooting code in global.asax:

```
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
...
    m_MaBaseModel = new MetaModel();
    m_MaBaseModel.RegisterContext(typeof(xxxx.MaBaseEntities), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });

    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("Favoris/{table}/{action}.aspx")
    {
        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert|BL01|ListDetails"
        }),
        Model = m_MaBaseModel
    });
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("Favoris/{table}/{IDActe}/{action}.aspx")
    {
        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            action = "List"
        }),
        Model = m_MaBaseModel
    });
```